# How do you configure eclipse to work with a project that wasn't created by it (java)

Tags: eclipse

I have been using the text editor gedit and the terminal for my latest project but I find that I have so many classes it would be more useful to be working with a separate directory for my .class and .java files so I can see what is going on more easily.

Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out how to get eclipse to work with a project that has already been made (or even one that was already made on eclipse with another computer!). This was not such a problem with two or three classes but I am getting to have so many that it is really tedious- It seems to want me to build a completely new project or nothing.

> EDIT (additional info):
>
> I don't think it will be possible to show the code of the project as I current have 12 classes for it but by the end I may have one or two more...
>
> I know how to make a project in eclipse. What I am not sure how to do it open a directory full of .java files in eclipse that were created using a text editor rather than in an eclipse project and get eclipse to accept it as a project.

Does anybody know how to achieve this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import your project into eclipse doing the following steps:

1. Create a new Java Project in Eclipse (By going to File -> New -> Java Project) select a name for the project and you can select finish
2. You have to import your existing code to eclipse, go to:

   File -> Import -> General -> FileSystem

   Then browse to the directory where your code is currently, and say you want to import into the project you created in step 1

Afterwards remember to go to the project properties (right click in the project folder while in the navigator view, for example) and make sure the java build path has the right source folders configured.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, you can use eclipse for any project previously created. Do you possibly have the code to show us how you are applying to the project in eclipse?

For example, you can create a project and class, then copy over starting from public static void main(String[] args) {

down to the bottom, then import the important stuff above the main class name.